# Devise with two kinds of users: student and professor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have used Devise before when just dealing with one kind of users.  In this app I am playing with, I have two kinds of users: students and professors.

I am planning on creating a Users table with common information and two tables with extra information for both students and professors.

However, I fail to see how would I deal with the sign up for these two different kinds with Devise.  I believe I will want to use CanCan for later on, but my main concern is when dealing with the sign up.  I basically want to be able to have two different kind of sign ups: one for professor and another one for students, and both of course will create a user too.

So, right now I am thinking on having:

```
devise_for :users
```

But, would it be better to just have

```
devise_for :students
devise_for :professors
```

?

Are there any resources that you guys could point me to? Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

If they have a lot of common logic and attributes, then create boolean attribute professor (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role). Otherwise create separate resources.